# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ... at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, azure

I know this question has been asked a few times before but the solutions given does not help me at all.
I have a Azure database and when my screen loads I get exception error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user
>   'ruan'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,  SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, 
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,  Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool,  DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject,  DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions,  DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection,  DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions,  DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, 
>   DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,  DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry,  DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
>   Ticketing.LogNewTicket.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Project\Project\Ticketing\Ticketing\LogNewTicket.aspx.cs:line
>   62  ClientConnectionId:92cb895a-8433-45d3-9c8c-19120f9a5c19 Error
>   Number:18456,State:1,Class:14

I assure my error happens here because it does not populate the drop down list.

```
try
            {
                //con.Open();

                ListItem blank = new ListItem("<Priority>");
                blank.Value = "0";
                ddlPriority.Items.Add(blank);

                string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Priority ";
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                            {
                                ListItem itemPriority = new ListItem(sqlDataReader.GetString(1).ToString());
                                itemPriority.Value = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                                ddlPriority.Items.Add(itemPriority);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSetPriority.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

My connection string looks like this:

My connection string:

```
Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=TicketsSupport;Integrated Security=False;User ID=ruan;Password=********;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

Connection string copied from visual studio in properties after connection to azure Database. Changed the  password that was **** to the actual one.

In web.config:

I have tried adding the following:

```
<machineKey validationKey="xxx" decryptionKey="xxx" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

AND

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

My master database has a user called "ruan"

I Used the following on my master:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals
```

When I added my user I only did the following:

```
CREATE LOGIN ruan WITH PASSWORD = 'abc123',
```

I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: Are you sure you have entered the correct password in the Connection String?

Comment: I connected my Azure database through visual studio  (SQL Server Object explorer) on my database in properties I copy that connection string. It showed password as **** but I replaced that with my actual password. Password must be working because I connected in visual studio to my DB

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: In VS: Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=TicketsSupport;Integrated Security=False;User ID=ruan;Password=********;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Comment: why windows authentication for Azure

Comment: The problem most likely is the "Windows" authentication mode...

Comment: I tried everything - <authentication mode="None" /> give the same exeption

Comment: Can you try copying the connection string from Azure Portal's SQL Database section and using it directly?

Comment: Tried that also the same issue. I wonder if the code that needs to populate the drop down list is not faulty?

Comment: I solved the issue by copping the connection string into the Try()Catch(). Not sure why its working but hey it does.